# Await value before useEffect runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that registers an **effect hook**, but it fails because inside the effect I need an object which at the time of running is not defined yet. Through debugging, I've noticed that the object (publicTypeIndex, in this case) is populated after the execution of the async callback.

Here is my code:

```
export function useNotesList() {

  const publicTypeIndex: any = usePublicTypeIndex();
  const [notesList, setNotesList] = React.useState<TripleDocument>();

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if (!publicTypeIndex) {

      return;
    }

    (async () => {

      const notesListIndex = publicTypeIndex.findSubject(solid.forClass, schema.TextDigitalDocument);

      if (!notesListIndex) {

        // If no notes document is listed in the public type index, create one:
        const notesList = await initialiseNotesList()

        if (notesList == null) {

          return;
        }

        setNotesList(notesList);
        return;
      }  else {

        // If the public type index does list a notes document, fetch it:
        const notesListUrl = notesListIndex.getRef(solid.instance);

        if (typeof notesListUrl !== 'string') {

          return;
        }
        const document = await fetchDocument(notesListUrl);
        setNotesList(document);
      }
    })();

  }, [publicTypeIndex])

  return notesList;
}
```

The usePublicTypeIndex function was written as follows:

```
export async function usePublicTypeIndex() {
  const [publicTypeIndex, setPublicTypeIndex] = React.useState<TripleDocument>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchPublicTypeIndex().then(fetchedPublicTypeIndex => {
      if (fetchedPublicTypeIndex === null) {

        console.log("The fetched public type index is null");
        return;
      }
      console.log("Fetched Public Type Index: ");
      console.log(fetchedPublicTypeIndex);
      setPublicTypeIndex(fetchedPublicTypeIndex);
    });
  }, []);

  return publicTypeIndex;
}
```

I'd like to find a way to wait for the `usePublicTypeIndex()` function to return before executing the `publicTypeIndex.findSubject(solid.forClass, schema.TextDigitalDocument);`code. What's the best way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`return` in `useEffect` used as `componentWillUnmount`, and for cleaning mostly.

In your case, just move the `async` func into the if block

---

```
  if (publicTypeIndex) {

  (async () => { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will always render at least once when the component mounts.. I ran into same issue as yours before while working on a react weather app.

i used `useRef` to overcome this issue:

```
// to stop the useEffect from rendering when the app is mounted for the first time
    const initialMount = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
        // to stop useEffect from rendering at the mounting of the app
        if (initialMount.current) {
            initialMount.current = false;
        } else {
            if (publicTypeIndex) {  
               // do all the stuff you have to do after your object is populated
            }
        }   
    },[publicTypeIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is technically correct, there is no better way to wait for the prop since the callback will run anyway. But you could clean up the code a bit, like:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (publicTypeIndex) {
      (async () => {
        const notesListIndex = publicTypeIndex.findSubject(
          solid.forClass,
          schema.TextDigitalDocument
        );

        if (!notesListIndex) {
          // If no notes document is listed in the public type index, create one:
          const notesList = await initialiseNotesList();

          if (notesList !== null) {
            setNotesList(notesList);
          }
        } else {
          // If the public type index does list a notes document, fetch it:
          const notesListUrl = notesListIndex.getRef(solid.instance);

          if (typeof notesListUrl === 'string') {
            const document = await fetchDocument(notesListUrl);
            setNotesList(document);
          }
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [publicTypeIndex]);
```

Basically there is no point with those returns, you could easily check for required conditions and then invoke the code.